# Bad Operand error in a Movie Session Program

Tags: java, comparable

I get the error:

```
"Bad Operand Types for Binary Operator ">"  first type: Time second type: Time"
```

Code:

```
public class MovieSession implements Comparable<MovieSession> {

    private String movieName;
    private char rating;
    private Time sessionTime;
    private SeatReservation[][] sessionSeats;
    public static int NUM_ROWS;
    public static int NUM_COLS;

    public MovieSession(String movieName, char rating, Time sessionTime) {
        this.movieName = movieName;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.sessionTime = sessionTime;
    }
This is the method where it gives me the error:

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MovieSession currentMovieSession) {

        if (this.sessionTime < currentMovieSession.sessionTime)
        {
            return -1;
        }
         else if (this.sessionTime > currentMovieSession.sessionTime) 
         {
            return 1;
         }
        if(this.sessionTime == currentMovieSession.sessionTime)
        {
            return this.movieName > currentMovieSession.movieName ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please change your question's title to represent the actual question you are asking. Also, you have a problem with types (`Bad Operand Types`), but you haven't shown us the data type of almost anything you are using in your code. We cannot do much without something like an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: also, you'll need to show the Movie Session variables `sessionTime`

Comment: Also, your last `if` statement is useless because your first `if/else if` will always return something first.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As stack overflow is new to me so am in the learning process

Answer (score 1):

`>` is a numerical comparison operator, and according to [JLS Sec 15.20.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1):

> The type of each of the operands of a numerical comparison operator must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.

Your `Time` type cannot be converted to a primitive numeric type, because it's not a primitive nor a primitive wrapper. Hence the error.

If you want to compare them, the `Time` time must implement `Comparable<Time>`, then you can write:

```
if (time1.compareTo(time2) > 0) { // Like "time1 > time2"
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help . Much appreciated  but have done same for my Time class. and now this is the movieSession class. So i was confused